# Set image to RepositoryItemPictureEdit in XtraGrid

Tags: repository, devexpress, xtragrid

I have `XtraGrid`, I've added a new column and set its `ColumnEdit` property to  `RepositoryItemPictureEdit`.
I have tried to set an image to it using `RepositoryItemPictureEdit1.Appearance.Image` but it does not populate after the form's load, any thoughts why?

I have 2011 version

Comment: can you show little code that how you are assigning/ reading image to assign to repositoryEditor control..?? that may help to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As i guess you are not assigning image to control in correct way. You can go through this DevExpress KB thread - [Why do I get the "No image data" text in the GridColumn with the PictureEdit in-place editor?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/KB/p/K18177.aspx)

Source : [Assigning an image to a RepositoryItemPictureEdit](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q325764.aspx)
you can use this approach also:
1) Set the column's FieldName property to the "Image" ,as your DataTable contains this Field
2) Set the Image DataColumn type to the Image value
3) Change the code and do not convert an image to a byte array.

Just set it as below:

```
RepositoryItemPictureEdit pictureEdit = gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add("PictureEdit") as RepositoryItemPictureEdit;

pictureEdit.SizeMode = PictureSizeMode.Zoom;

pictureEdit.NullText = " ";

gridView1.Columns["Picture"].ColumnEdit = pictureEdit;
```

*To make the editor load images, the underlying data type should correspond to the [RepositoryItemPictureEdit.PictureStoreMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsRepositoryRepositoryItemPictureEdit_PictureStoreModetopic) property value*

If you want to display image in cell then you can use CustomDrawCell Event

Here `ImageStream` is a property that store image.

```
 public Stream ImageStream { get; set; }
```

you can use it as below:

```
    if (profile != null)
    {
          imageStream = MyObj.ImageStream; // this image saved as stream
    }

}

if (imageStream != null)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imageStream), e.Bounds);
    if (cellValue.Condition== "XXXX")
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(e.Cache.GetPen(Color.Red), e.Bounds);
    }

    e.DisplayText = text;
    Rectangle r = e.Bounds;
    Rectangle w = new Rectangle(r.X, r.Y - 5, r.Width, r.Height);
    //Draw the cell value
    e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, e.DisplayText, w);
    e.Bounds.Inflate(-2, -2);
}
```

More References:
[How to put icons in grid cells](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A900.aspx)
[How to display external images in grid columns if the data source only contains links to the images](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/A2707.aspx)
[RepositoryItemPictureEdit Load Image](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q270783.aspx)
[How to load a picture into the repositoryitemPictureEdit](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q100485.aspx)
[RepositoryItemPictureEdit default empty image](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q394538.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this answer -- helped me tremendously with a vector image issue I was having. DevExpress post here -- https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T152504